# Reset options in <select> using React

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to learn how to reset the options after I submit my form. I am unsure of how to accomplish this task. Any advice is greatly appreciated!

```
import '../App.css'
import React, { useState } from 'react';
function Interface() {
const [choices, setChoices] = useState({
    selectValue: 'Pick Reason',
    damageValue: 'Pick Reason',
    submitted: false,
    default: 'Pick Option',
})


let handleCart = function(e){
   return setChoices({...choices,selectValue: e.target.value})

}

let handleDamage = function(e){
    return setChoices({...choices,damageValue: e.target.value}) 

}


let buttonSub = function(e){
    e.preventDefault()
    alert(`your teacher is ${choices.selectValue} your damage is ${choices.damageValue}`)
    setChoices({selectValue: '', damageValue: '', submitted: !true})
}


  return (

    <div className="App">
        <h1>Chromebook Deposit Form</h1>
        <form>
            <div className="form-group">
               <label>Select Whose Cart your chromebook belongs too</label>
               <select className="form-control w-50 " id="cart" onChange={handleCart} placeholder='hi'>
                <option>{choices.default}</option>
                <option>Emily Freitag</option>
                <option>Santoro</option>
                <option>Warner</option>
                <option>Baltzell</option>
               </select>
               <hr></hr>
               <label>Select Your Reason For deposit</label>
               <select className="form-control w-50 " id="cart" onChange={handleDamage}>
                 <option>{choices.default}</option>
                <option>Broken Screen</option>
                <option>Broken Keys</option>
                <option>Broken Case</option>
                <option>Other</option>
               </select>





               <button className="button" onClick={buttonSub}>Submit Information</button>

            </div>

        </form>
    </div>
  );
}
export default Interface;
```

I have tried setting the values dynamically which works but I can't figure out how to make it display a certain one after submitting the form.

Answer (score 2):

You aren't fully controlling your inputs. You are providing a change handler, but not a value. Try simply adding a value to the selects:

```js
<select 
  className="form-control w-50 " 
  id="cart" 
  value={choices.selectValue} 
  onChange={handleCart} 
  placeholder='hi'
>

...

<select 
  className="form-control w-50 " 
  id="cart" 
  value={choices.damageValue} 
  onChange={handleDamage}
>
```

Then on submit, you can just update the state value of the selects to what you want them to reset to (it looks like you already are).

However, unless react handles this automatically and I'm just not aware, you'll need to set the value of each option too. The string of the label will be good enough for this case:

```js
<select 
  className="form-control w-50 " 
  id="cart" 
  value={choices.damageValue} 
  onChange={handleDamage}
>
  <option value={'default'}>{choices.default}</option>
  <option value={'Broken Screen'}>Broken Screen</option>
  <option value={'Broken Keys'}>Broken Keys</option>
  <option value={'Broken Case'}>Broken Case</option>
  <option value={'Other'}>Other</option>
</select>
```

Also: this `submitted: !true` seems unnecessary. Just use `false` unless the `!` is a typo.